# android get list of images from mysql database

Tags: php, android

I can load one image from mysql databse using Async Task, but now i want to load 5 images and show them in a list view so i want first to know how to make **doInbackground method** return a list of images got from mysql databse :

```
 @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            String id = params[0];
            String add = "http://192.168.1.11/save/load_image_from_db.php?id=" + id;
            URL url;
            Bitmap image = null;
            try {
                final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                //options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                //options.inSampleSize = 4;
                //options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                url = new URL(add);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.getInputStream(),null,options);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return image;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you have to return an ArrayList of images, the code will be something like this,, (**note:** I have not tests this code)

```
    @Override protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
     String id = params[0]; 

    String add1 = "http://192.168.1.11/save/load_image_from_db.php?id=" + id; 
    String add2="http://another photo";
    String add3="http://another photo";
    String[] adds={add1, add2, add3};
    URL url;

    ArrayList <Bitmap> imageList=new ArrayList();

     Bitmap image = null; 

    for (int i=0;i<adds.length;i++){

    try { 
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options(); null //options.inJustDecodeBounds = true; //options.inSampleSize = 4;  null//options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

 url = new URL(adds[i]); null HttpURLConnection connection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();  nullimage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.getInputStream(),null,options);  null} catch (MalformedURLException e) { e.printStackTrace();  null} catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();  null}

    imageList.add( image);
    image=null;
    }
     return imageList; 
    }
```

Comment: can't we get list of image from one URL ?

Comment: each image has it's url,, what do you mean by list of images from one url??

list of image has list of url, that is the correct one..

Yes, of course you can get some images and load them into the listview

Comment: i'm wondering if it is possible to write a php script that displays all the images stored in mysql database, and use this url in android apps to get all the images from just one url

Comment: You can use php to fetch the data from the database then encode it to JSON,,, then from the mobile get the JSON and download images and texts form the website..
Volley is the best to do it..

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Bitmap>> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Bitmap> doInBackground(String... params) {
        ArrayList<Bitmap> bmps = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            String id = params[i];
            String add = "http://192.168.1.11/save/load_image_from_db.php?id=" + id;
            URL url;
            Bitmap image = null;
            try {
                final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                //options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                //options.inSampleSize = 4;
                //options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                url = new URL(add);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.getInputStream(), null, options);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            bmps.add(image);
        }

        return bmps;
    }
}
```

You would then call the execute method with an array of ids... et voila!